Unable to Receive Subscription Responses from Avaya IP Office Using MTCTI-3 Protocol
I am integrating with an Avaya IP Office system using the MTCTI-3 protocol in Java. I have successfully established a WebSocket connection and verified that ping-pong communication works as expected. However, when I send a subscription request, it reaches the server (confirmed via Avaya SysMonitor), but I am not receiving any acknowledgment or response from the server.
What I Have Done:

Established WebSocket Connection: The WebSocket connection is active, and I can see the 101 Switching Protocols response during the handshake.

Verified Ping-Pong Communication:

Sending a ping:
ws.sendPing(ByteBuffer.wrap("keepalive".getBytes()));

Receiving a pong:


 @Override  
 public CompletionStage<?> onPong(WebSocket webSocket, ByteBuffer message) {  
  System.out.println("Pong received: " + new String(message.array()));  
  return null;  
 }


This communication works perfectly, and I can see the corresponding logs in Avaya IP Office SysMonitor.


Subscription Payload:

I am sending the following Protobuf Message to subscribe to a hunt group queue:

 Message  
{  
 subscribe  
{  
   requestid=2  
   subscribe_id=7500  
   queue  
   {  
       flags=0x3  
       ccflags=0x40039  
       name=TestCTI  
   }  
 }  
} 


Serialized Protobuf payload:
1A 18 08 02 10 D2 1D 22 10 08 03 10 39 80 04 1A 05 53 61 6C 65 73

Framed with a 4-byte length prefix:
00 00 00 18 1A 18 08 02 10 D2 1D 22 10 08 03 10 39 80 04 1A 05 53 61 6C 65 73

The request is sent using:
ws.sendBinary(ByteBuffer.wrap(framedMessage), true);



Checked Logs in SysMonitor: The subscription request reaches the server (confirmed in logs). However, I do not see any acknowledgment or response for the subscription.

Simulated Activity on Subscribed Queue: Calls are being made to the "Sales" hunt group to generate events, but no responses are received on the WebSocket.

Implemented Response Handling:

onBinary() is used to process server responses:
@Override  
public CompletionStage<?> onBinary(WebSocket webSocket, ByteBuffer data, boolean last) {  
  try {  
    IpoMtcti3.Message message = IpoMtcti3.Message.parseFrom(data.array());  
    System.out.println("Server Response: " + message.toString());  
  } catch (Exception e) {  
  System.err.println("Error parsing response: " + e.getMessage());  
 }  
webSocket.request(1);  
return null;  



}




Observations:

WebSocket connection and ping-pong communication work without issues.

The subscription message is received by the server (confirmed via logs), but there is no acknowledgment or subsequent events.


Questions:

Are there specific requirements or configurations for IP Office to handle subscription requests properly?

Is the Protobuf payload or framing incorrect for this type of subscription?

How can I debug this further to identify why the server does not send a response?


Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if additional details or logs are required.
Note : I have tried this code Avaya IPO with MTCTI-3 Api
